# Дано натуарльное чило n. Найти наибольшую и наименьшую цифры в записи это числа

Tags: javascript, c

Олимпиадная задачка. Напишите, пожалуйста, решение на JS или Си.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вас научить находить остаток от деления на 10?

Comment: во те на питоне: `lambda n: (max(str(n)), min(str(n)))`

Answer (score 1):

В порядке развлечения

```js
const N = 123456;
const res = N.toString().split('').reduce((a, v) => {
  if (!(v >= a.min))
    a.min = v;
  if (!(v <= a.max))
    a.max = v;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Можно короче - `Math.min(...[...N+''])`. Ну и аналогично для наибольшей..